# How to replace string between two strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I had following string ,

`const str= "this is harp//foo.eps and harp//data.eps"`

I need to replace the string between `harp` to `.eps`

My code below,

`const str  = "this is harp//foo.eps and harp//data.eps"`

`const data = str.replace(/\harp.*\eps/, 'www.imge.jpg');`

`console.log(data);`

it was returning output below,

`this is www.imge.jpg`

But expected output

`this is www.imge.jpg and www.imge.jpg`

Comment: I think you want the non-greedy version `.*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make use non-greedy (`?`) search and global (`/g`) modifier:

```js
const str  = "this is a harp//foo.eps and a harp//data.eps and harp//data.eps"
const data = str.replace(/harp(.*?)eps/g, 'www.imge.jpg');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the replace all function and the following regex

```js
const str  = "this is harp//foo-two.eps and harp//data-9.eps"
const newSTr = str.replaceAll(/harp\/\/[A-Za-z\-0-9]+\.eps/g, 'www.imge.jpg')
console.log(newSTr);
```